# Meaning of the word "butterglance" to describe a woman's way of looking at someone

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I found this word in a rhyme inscribed on the fly leaf of a book of American poetry and dated 1878. You can see the poem listed in [Edith Wharton's Library: a catalogue](https://books.google.com/books?id=ax8gAQAAIAAJ&q=butterglance&dq=butterglance&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8manYuLbPAhXD7YMKHYU0APUQ6AEIIjAB), which was written by George Ransden and published by Stone Through in 1999:

> pc One poem marked in the Contents list and that one and another in the text, possibly by the writer of the rhyme on the flyleaf:
>
> In this book dear girl/ Find a truthful utterance /
>
> For the thoughts that whirl / Oft expressed in butterglance"
>
> [Signed] WBB<sup>3</sup>

I can't find anything in the O.E.D., and [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=butterglance) does not reveal too much either, aside from the aforementioned source and a couple of potential mentions which can't be previewed.

You can also find [what looks like an original handwritten version of the poem](http://sheilaliming.com/ewl/items/show/17) which can be seen on the Edith Wharton's library website, hosted by [Sheila Liming](http://sheilaliming.com/), Assistant Professor of English in the University of North Dakota. It is handwritten on a copy of The Poems of Thomas Bailey Aldrich, published by Boston Ticknor and Fields in 1865. Above it is inscribed "Edith Jones - Oct. 11th 1878", which may be an indicator of who owned that copy of the book, and when she first got it.

Comment: Can you give more context? From that line it's not clear why you're saying it's a woman's way of looking at someone.

Comment: If this wasn't written and you were writing something you had heard I would say that it actually said 'but a glance'. Perhaps butterglance was a colloquialism.

Comment: Or a jokey misspelling.

Comment: There is a recent slang term of  (probably) similar provenance: _butterface_, defined in Jonathon Green, _Chambers Dictionary of Slang_ as follows: "**butterface** n. {i.e. _but her face_} {2000s} (_US black_) a female whose body is very attractive, but who has an unattractive face." It seems likely that _butterglance_ is a contraction of "but her glance."

Comment: I should've put more thought into this edit: This looks like it was a personal copy of a book from a novelist named [Edith Wharton](http://tinyurl.com/zmrscb5) who was born on Jan. 24 1862 in New York with the maiden name Edith Newbold Jones. She returned from living in Europe to New York in the year 1872. I hypothesize this was probably a parting or a homecoming gift to her from a friend with the initials W.W.B. I figure this is noteworthy because if butterglance is regional slang, it probably originates from New York, as France, Germany, Italy and Spain are dominated by other languages.

Comment: @SGR [Eggcorn?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @SGR and @Sven Yargs, this seems more than likely to be a contraction of '*but a glance*' and possibly a play on words.

> There is a recent slang term of (probably) similar provenance: butterface, defined in Jonathon Green, Chambers Dictionary of Slang as follows: "**butterface** n. {i.e. but her face} {2000s} (US black) a female whose body is very attractive, but who has an unattractive face." It seems likely that *butterglance* is a contraction of "but her glance." 
>   -Sven Yargs